# React Js newbie qustion about styling

Tags: reactjs

I look informations about styling components in react.
For example I have a button and I want to change background color after click.
Atm I just change predefined css classes, but i can do it in other way.
What is most common and recommended practice?

Comment: Each component usually will have an attached styling file for example if your component's name is `Home` you'll have the main `Home.js` file and `Home.css` file that your styling will reside inside you can do any styling you want in there just remember when using a class to type `className` instead of `class`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline styling to change css depend on state of your component like:

```
const Example = (props) => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

    let styleStatus = isActive ?
        {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            fontSize: '20',
        } :
        {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            fontSize: '15',
        };

    return <div>
        <div style={styleStatus}> {isActive ? 'Active' : 'Deactive'} </div>;
        <button onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}> Click to change css </button>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this, either through css or through reactjs. Through reactjs if you are using hooks you are going to want to setup a state variable such as

```
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

return (
   <button style={{backgroundColor: buttonClicked ? "green" : "blue"}} onClick={() => setButtonClicked(!buttonClicked)} />
)
```